# using change String format to NumberFomat and my exception is Cannot format given Object as a Number

Tags: java, spring

I want to change my string numeric number like this `1 000 048,35` but my exception is `Cannot format given Object as a Number` Any help into this would be appreciated!

```
 Document document = convertStringToDocument(response.getBody());
 String error = Objects.requireNonNull(document).getElementsByTagName("status").item(0).getTextContent();
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
 String value = nf.format(Long.toString(Long.parseLong(Objects.requireNonNull(document)
                .getElementsByTagName("paramValue").item(0).getTextContent())/100));//here exception
 List<ValueItem> valueItems = new LinkedList<>();
 ValueItem balance = new ValueItem();
 balance.setKey("balance");
 balance.setName("Баланс");
 balance.setValue(value);
 valueItems.add(balance);
 additionalSuppliersReturn.setValueItems(valueItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "1000048.35";
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("sk","SK"));
Number number = new BigDecimal(str);
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
```

The problem is comma where you can not divide it to big decimal or double value. You can replace with dot.

```
str = str.replace(",",".");
```

At the simplest solution you can use :

```
String str = "1000048,35";
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("sk","SK")).parse(str));
```

Final Solution :

```
    try {
        String str = "1000048,35";
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
        Number number = numberFormat.parse(str);
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Example of double

```
Double dbl = new Double("100004835");
System.out.println(dbl);
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("sk", "SK"));
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(dbl);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal(100));
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(bigDecimal));
```

Comment: thank you bro i solve problem but born new problam i parse to NumberFormat and it changes only rigth size for example paramValue is 18814589 i change it to double and divide to 100 value is 188145,89 when i setValue to balance in my app it is 188145 but not last number ,89  can you help me bro

Comment: If you put it into double value it won't remove ,89

Comment: I updated answer